# Use an alias defined by the class imported

Tags: c#

I have a namespace with a class:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    public class Enormous // My implementation of BigInteger
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I want all classes import myNamespace.Enormous can use the class without the capital letter (simulating a native type):

```
enormous foo = new enormous("3333333333"); // "enormous", not "Enormous"
```

I've found it's possible define an alias with:

```
using enormous = myNamespace.Enormous;
```

But the class which import myNamespace.Enormous can't use the alias. The unique class can use the alias is who define it.

I think is not appropiate rename the class as "enormous" instead of "Enormous" (in C#, classes start with capital letter). Then, can I define a type of "external alias" with C#? I don't want add options to the compiler, just code.

Note: I can't create the alias inheriting the class with a simple line of code (public class enormous : Enormous { }) because the class Enormous has a constructor and more things.

Comment: Care to explain why you need this?

Comment: `class enormous : Enormous { }`?

Comment: May be irrelevant, but you forgot to put `public` keyword before the class.

Comment: This doesn't appear to add any benefit to your code and would likely just confuse other developers.  Consistency is key.

Comment: @Steve "simulating a native type".